What is the Taylor series of the expectation value of an observable in quantum mechanics?
I recently came across a form of the expectation value of an observable, but a Taylor series (I think?) was taken up to second-order:
\begin{equation}
\langle O\rangle = \langle O\rangle_{C=0} + \langle\frac{dO}{dC} \cdot C\rangle + ...
\end{equation}
where the initial state is evolved according to
\begin{equation}
|\psi_f\rangle = e^{-iCH}|\psi_i\rangle
\end{equation}
Is this correct for when the parameter $C$ is small? It would be nice to give me some intuition regarding this!

Do you have a reference?

@Mauricio no. I just wrote this down.
